# how do I get a data frame's variable counts and percentages in R (rpy2)?

Tags: r, dataframe, rpy2

I am running rpy2 in Google Colab and would like to know how to find a data frame's variable counts and percentages.

In Python I would use df.value_counts(), but didn't find an equvalent function in R. There are posts bout finding counts for a specific value but not counts of all the data frame's variables.

Comment: Take a look at this example `sapply(mtcars[, c(2,8,8,10, 11)], table)`

Comment: where can I find the example?